# Current Item:Version has wrong version number in SP 2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, document-library, versioning, version

I have a workflow on a library. It first checks if the `Current Item:Version` ends in ".0" (to see if it's a major version). I have a Log statement at the beginning of the workflow to record the version number.

This workflow works most of the time, but occasionally it "misses". For example, if I look at the Version History of document "X", there are no minor versions. There were 5 versions checked in (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0). When I look at the trigger history, my Log statements show the version numbers being 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 3.1, 4.0., 4.1, 5.0.

So for some reason a minor version shows up in the Workflow even though the document was never saved as a minor version? And what happened to version 3.0? Is it a timing problem? Do I need a pause statement somewhere?

Comment: At a time only one instance of workflow runs for a single item in list/library. Maybe that's the reason version 3.0 is missing (if instance of workflow for 2.1 already running & new version checked in).

Comment: Would multiple instances of the workflow run on a single update/check-in? E.g., if I check in a document as a major version 2.0, I see in the workflow log that there is a version 1.1 and then 2.0. I can't figure out why. In the Doc version history, it only shows versions 1.0 and 2.0.